# How can I highlight a div inside an overlay using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would like to click on a `div` and `highlight, this`div`is inside an`overlay` popup. I have my jquery code added below, but the highlight is not happening. Could someone please advise on how can I fix this ?

html added displayed below

```js
$('#projectDataHereToDisplay > .row').click(function() {
  $(this).removeClass("highlight");
  $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: #ebdb34;
}

.cleaner {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
}

.rows {
  width: 1000px;
  min-height: 80px;
}

.rowsAlt {
  background-color: #edece8;
}

.cols {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.col1 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
}

.col2 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
}

.col3 {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
}

.col4 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
}

.col5 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
}

.col6 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
}

#row2 {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 83%;
  margin: 20px 0px 0px 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="projectDataHereToDisplay" class="column">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="row2" class="rows rowsAlt">
      <div class="col1">FLG</div>
      <div class="col2">sun</div>
      <div class="col3">man,lion</div>
      <div class="col4"></div>
      <div class="col5">Byes</div>
      <div class="cleaner">Add here</div>
      <div class="col6"><a class="projecteditLink" href="">Edit Link</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div id="row2" class="rows rowsAlt">
      <div class="col1">FLG</div>
      <div class="col2">sun</div>
      <div class="col3">man,lion</div>
      <div class="col4"></div>
      <div class="col5">Byes</div>
      <div class="cleaner">Add here</div>
      <div class="col6"><a class="projecteditLink" href="">Edit Link</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly? your code working fine, just you need to use `toggleClass` instead of using `addClass` and `removeClass` in a same time!

Answer (score 0):

It will solve your question. Now it will highlight your row.

```js
$('.rows').click(function() {

  $(this).removeClass("highlight");
  $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
```

```html
<style>
.highlight {
  background: #ebdb34 !important;
}

.cleaner {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
}

.rows {
  width: 1000px;
  min-height: 80px;
}

.rowsAlt {
  background-color: #edece8;
}

.cols {
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.col1 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
}

.col2 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
}

.col3 {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
}

.col4 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
}

.col5 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
}

.col6 {
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  padding: 20px 10px 10px 20px;
}

#row2 {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: relative;
  width: 83%;
  margin: 20px 0px 0px 100px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="projectDataHereToDisplay" class="column">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="row2" class="rows rowsAlt">
      <div class="col1">FLG</div>
      <div class="col2">sun</div>
      <div class="col3">man,lion</div>
      <div class="col4"></div>
      <div class="col5">Byes</div>
      <div class="cleaner">Add here</div>
      <div class="col6"><a class="projecteditLink" href="">Edit Link</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div id="row2" class="rows rowsAlt">
      <div class="col1">FLG</div>
      <div class="col2">sun</div>
      <div class="col3">man,lion</div>
      <div class="col4"></div>
      <div class="col5">Byes</div>
      <div class="cleaner">Add here</div>
      <div class="col6"><a class="projecteditLink" href="">Edit Link</a></div>
```

Comment: I have added the same code and it not working for me.

Comment: I did two changes. One in css  and second in the javascript. .highlight {
  background: #ebdb34 !important;
}    Javascript code                                        $('.rows').click(function() {

  $(this).removeClass("highlight");
  $(this).addClass("highlight");
});

Comment: I saw that applied the same changes.

Comment: Hard refresh your browser. press ctrl + shift +r

Comment: Is it showing the correct output when you click it run code snippet button?

Comment: I  had done a hard refresh. Yes, It is showing the correct output in the code snippet..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202091/discussion-between-kaleemullah-and-soccerway).

Comment: Dont know why ....Is that due to my div is inside the `overlay` ?